# Is there a way to process credit card payments in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, payment

We have a silverlight application using asmx webservices.

I want to give the ability to users to process their orders using credit card or paypal.
IS this doable?! 
 Is this something that can done in the webservice.

Any References would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate PayPal to your Silverlight application. I can't give some code sample here because code is too big but can recommend [Silverlight-4-Problem-Design-Solution](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Silverlight-4-Problem-Design-Solution.productCd-0470534044.html) by Wrox. Chapter 11 of this book is about PayPal integration.
Also take a look to a [post on silverlight forum](http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/192266/448789.aspx).
Hope this will help.